# Update a count of the number of polygons which intesect with polygons in the update table

Tags: sql-server, st-intersects

I have a table with 1km squares as polygons and I want to update a column with the number of spatial intersects in another table of polygons. Something like this [if count could be used here];

```
Update KmStats
SET RecCount = COUNT(*)
From KmStats
INNER JOIN SP_Records 
   On KmStats.SP_geometry.STIntersects(SP_Records.SP_GEOMETRY) = 1
```

All the polygons in SP_Records are aligned to the same grid and are either small enough to fit in a 1km sq or are 1km or 2km sq polygons.

Answer (score 1):

I've done it long-hand. Using mod on the eastings and northings

```
 Select Easting - [Easting] % 1000 As Easting, Northing - [Northing] % 1000     As Northing, Count(*) As CountOf
 Into rpt_Counts
 From SP_Records
 Group By Easting - [Easting] % 1000, Northing - [Northing] % 1000
```

This gets me the basic result I want I then do a bit more manipulation which I have to do on two tables and then sum the results. It also works fast.